# How to calculate differents radiogroups?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, testing

im making a test with 12 questions in android studio and would love to know how to create a result button that calculate 12 radiogroups with 3 radiobuttons each one? i added sharedPrefences in each question to save the selected button.

```
RadioButton radioButton31, radioButton32, radioButton33, radioButton34, radioButton35, radioButton36;

RadioGroup radioGroup11, radioGroup12;

Button calcularButton;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity (new Intent(this, MainActivity12.class));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main13);

    txt31=findViewById(R.id.txt31);
    txt32=findViewById(R.id.txt32);

    radioButton31=findViewById(R.id.radioButton31);
    radioButton32=findViewById(R.id.radioButton32);
    radioButton33=findViewById(R.id.radioButton33);
    radioButton34=findViewById(R.id.radioButton34);
    radioButton35=findViewById(R.id.radioButton35);
    radioButton36=findViewById(R.id.radioButton36);

    calcularButton=findViewById(R.id.calcularButton);

    radioGroup11 = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup11);
    RadioButton checkedButton11 = findViewById(radioGroup11.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

    radioGroup11.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("RespuestasTest", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("radioButton33", radioButton33.isChecked()); // first argument is a name of a data that you will later use to retrieve it and the second argument is a value that will be stored
            editor.putBoolean("radioButton32", radioButton32.isChecked());
            editor.putBoolean("radioButton31", radioButton31.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
        }
    });

    radioGroup12 = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup12);
    RadioButton checkedButton12 = findViewById(radioGroup12.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

    radioGroup12.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("RespuestasTest", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("radioButton36", radioButton36.isChecked()); 
            editor.putBoolean("radioButton35", radioButton35.isChecked());
            editor.putBoolean("radioButton34", radioButton34.isChecked());
            editor.commit();

        }
    });




    calcularButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity13.this, MainActivity14.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

I have 5 intents for this test, so the result will be based on the high option selected. For example..
Question A    B    C     Question 2   A    B    C

so, we have 12 questions with 3 options, should give an int num like 1, 2 or 3, then count each answer, if we have more 1's than 2 or 3, then will be an other intent to that page to show the info of result 1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom view with RadioGroup and can use that view at your main layout. Here is a sample with code:

[CustomView](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ivancse58/fbfb80e4d1d112498ab48fd2769dccaf/raw/16a908e448d6bd226ec0d8b374630357065c698b/MyQuestion.kt)

[CustomViewXml](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ivancse58/8aeeac0bc8009bf03ecc16a772c3b9c9/raw/78d2f57170e442563f8982181c9f51865b7feabe/layout_my_question.xml)

[And inside your activity:](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ivancse58/abee7ac2c7c37105986fdbaeddb14c27/raw/9b0487d5756a15c0aaac286b480b38da2ec2a6b5/activity_main_question_list.xml)

[Activity with Listener](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ivancse58/a9d2bb78995f9cdb49698cc707215445/raw/2849bfbafa318ba97db92207b4a1cb897a597111/MainQuestionListActivity.kt)